# 401 challenges with URLSession for NTLM

Tags: swift

I'm using a custom URLSession with a delegate to handle the 401 challenges received from our NTLM authentication web api.  I would expect to only receive a challenge for the first api call however I get one for each unique endpoint I call.  Is there any way to provide the stored credentials with each call to avoid a 401 every time?  My basic session setup is below.

```
let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default

let delegate = MySessionDelegate()
let session = URLSession(configuration: config, delegate: delegate, delegateQueue: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I found while working with an API using NTLM authentication. Essentially, you need to set the delegate of your `URLSessionConfiguration` instance to your ViewController's class (or anything that subclasses `NSObject`) and implement the `func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void)` function of the `URLSessionDelegate` protocol.

The way authentication is handled is that when `URLSession` makes a request it first negotiates the authentication method (see [NSURLProtectionSpace Authentication Method Constants](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlprotectionspace/nsurlprotectionspace_authentication_method_constants#2951431)) and then based on which authentication method you choose (in this case, we reject everything that's not `NSURLAuthenticationMethodNTLM`), we get authenticated with the server.

The following code was tested with Swift 5.1 and Xcode 11:

```
import Cocoa
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

class NTLMAuthentication: NSObject {

    private let baseURL = "<insert base URL here>"

    private let username: String
    private let password: String

    lazy private var session: URLSession = {
        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        return URLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
    }()

    init(username: String, password: String) {
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
    }

    func authenticate() {
        let url = URL(string: baseURL)
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard error == nil else {
                print("An error occurred")
                return
            }

            let htmlData = String(bytes: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
            print(htmlData)
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}

extension NTLMAuthentication : URLSessionDelegate {
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {

        print("got challenge")
        print(challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod)

        guard challenge.previousFailureCount == 0 else {
            print("too many failures")
            completionHandler(.cancelAuthenticationChallenge, nil)
            return
        }

        guard challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodNTLM else {
            completionHandler(.rejectProtectionSpace, nil)
            return
        }

        let credentials = URLCredential(user: self.username, password: self.password, persistence: .forSession)
        completionHandler(.useCredential, credentials)
    }
}
```

Note that the line `PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true` is required to run this code in a playground as otherwise the code will not finish running before the playground terminates.

Comment: this doesn't address the question.  this solution would still get a 401 challenge for every new url